# (u)intN_t are always aligned to N bit?

Tags: c, struct, memory-alignment

1. For example, on architecture x86, 64-bit integers can be safe aligned to 32 bits without a penalty, because still have to do the calculations in parts: the integer simply does not fit in the register. For __(u)int128 everything is the same. But usually they are aligned to the same number of bits as they store. Is this true for all modern and possible future architectures?
2. Could the same int8_t or int16_t be aligned to 32 bits somewhere?

Speaking about the future, I mean not revolutionary architecture, which die even before being born. A byte de facto contains 8 bits, two's complement, flat addressing, pages, etc. The development vector is already set and there will be no deviations. But the issue of alignment is interesting.

Comment: `Is this true for all modern and possible future architectures?` This is too broad. Do you have any specific arch in mind?

Comment: "usually" is probably likely to be true for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Choose only one language please.

Comment: You might have an architecture with `char`, `short`, `int` all being 32 bits (of `sizeof` being 1) on a machine with "32 bits" bytes

Comment: It is difficult to make predictions, especially about the future.

Comment: Of course, I'm considering a binary architecture with two's complement integers - It is used now and will be in the future, all sorts of qubits and three-state logic are too exotic and they can be neglected.If the described behavior when aligning numbers that are larger than the register size is true, then why do not the compilers use this feature? Or is it used somewhere on some kind of abi or processor architectures?

Comment: 1) You are aware that the variables doesn't **have** to be placed on, e.g. 4 byte aligned addresses, right? 2) What do mean by "why do not the compilers use this feature?"

Comment: @4386427 I'm talking about packed alignment without a penalty, for example, int64_t aligned to 32 bits on x86.

Comment: @Stargateur It does not really matter, although c++ could make additional restrictions, getting rid of the support of legacy architectures.

Comment: @cejun So you are an expert in C and C++ and already know they will only some additional restrictions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64-bit integers are 4 byte aligned on x86, but if you take other 32-bit architectures like ARM, MIPS and PowerPC, then you can see that 64-bit integers are required to be aligned at 8 byte boundary.

This is not processor specific though, as 64-bit loads and stores are are emulated in software using two 4-byte accesses. Instead, this is a part of ABI used by C compilers. I can only guess why they chose to do this, most likely due to performance: regardless of the size of CPU registers, CPU bus is likely be wider than 32-bits today, so loading/storing 8-byte integers is faster if they are 8-byte aligned. Another reasons is that for atomic operations 8-byte integer still has to be aligned at 8-byte boundary.

So yes, `(u)intN_t` are always aligned to `N` bits on x86_64, ARM, AArch64, PowerPC, PowerPC64, MIPS, MIPS64. It is up to you to decide if this is "modern enough". But in the future it is likely that 8-byte integers will use 8-byte alignment due to performance, regardless of width of processors GPRs.

Situation with non-standard 128-bit and greater integers might be different though. As data is usually fetched from cache in cache lines (usually 64-bytes), it is more efficient to make them 128-bit aligned too, but implementation might not choose to do so for whatever reason. But 128-bit integers are non-standard, you might still need to provide platform-dependent solution for those, so you can "fix" their alignment too. Currently GCC keeps `__int128` 16-byte aligned on AArch64, x86_64, PowerPC64.

As for future architectures, I would say that they have to provide similar environment, otherwise they will have issues with lots of software anyway. Portability of most software is highly exaggerated.Is it possible for such uncommon architecture to become popular this days? Unlikely. Do you need to support it? Probably not, it might be so special your software won't work on it anyway.

Comment: @4386427 No it is not, unless you count non-standard things like `__int128`. But those really should be 128-bit aligned to improve performance.

Comment: @4386427 Packed structures have nothing to do with type alignment. This is situation when programmer explicitly asks to change member field alignment for specific case and has nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: @4386427 The question was about alignment of standard types. Those types have very specific alignment. It doesn't matter how you can place them in memory - you are free to do whatever you want. It is important to understand how compiler will place them for you. This is the only thing that matters.

Comment: @Ivan: To make your point even stronger, note that passing `&packed_struct->some_int` to a function expecting `int *` **will crash** on many real targets. Packed types are really invalid nonsense that are nog handled consistently or safely by compilers.

Comment: @4386427 *Have you ever used packed struct?*  Packed structures are non-portable while also being a wonderful way to raise a `SIGBUS`/`SIGSEGV` on different types of hardware.